# Bootstrap 3.3.4 picture grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on several pages with 15-20 pictures per page and looking for the way to arrange it via 4-3-1 grid. Something like this:

[**Fiddle preview**](https://jsfiddle.net/d3woethq/1/embedded/result/) to code block below.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>

    <!-- some more divs here -->

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm satisfied with this look, however, problems occur as soon as we introduce pictures with slightly different dimensions.

[**Fiddle preview**](https://jsfiddle.net/d3woethq/embedded/result/) to code block below.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x125" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x125" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>

    <!-- some more divs here -->

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/330x130" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now details. I don't know how to get it done, but I see 2 possible ways to solve this: a) resize every single picture to the "standard" (lets say 350x150px) - and this has to be done browser side; or b) vertically align pictures within the rows displayed, 4-3-1 grid has to stay.
I've also tried to mess with `row-eq-height` class, but that didn't take me far.

How would you tackle this problem and why?

I thank you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a couple of ways you could look at doing this. 
If you do not want to look at resizing all your images to the same height and width.

You probably have these options I use in this **[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4kjg5xsk/embedded/result/)**.

The first image (top Left) uses this...

```
.image-1 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/550x350);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-color: bisque;
}
```

Using this above you will lose coverage top and bottom, but your block will stay the same height and continue to flow with bootstrap.

Then the following 3 images use this...

```
.image-2 {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The only difference is the `background-size:` as you can see.

When we use background-position:center; we focus the image on the center and as the image resizes it will maintain focus but lose the outer view of the image. 
As you will see in the Fiddle if you resize the window.
Do this(resize) so you can watch all the images and how they act when resize.
I have each div set to a set overall height.

There is another set of images below your main set all set to the same image size so you can actually see how they change with the above options too.

Obviously using bootstrap and trying to use different height blocks is always going to be an issue but these demo options may help you do what you want to do here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that you're putting everything in one row.
If you only put four images in a row, this will work even with differing image heights.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x125" class="img-responsive thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x125" class="img-responsive thumbnail" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x100" class="img-responsive thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x120" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
      </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x130" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/320x100" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/330x150" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x120" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/330x130" class="img-responsive thumbnail">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought about separate rows, but I don't really like how it looks in the "tablet view" (every 4th pic under 3rd) plus I don't have exact number of pictures per page which adds complications to working with templates. Anyways, thank you for quick reply.