# Bootstrap: How can I keep responsive images the same height even if they are not?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a gallery with images in different widths like this:

```
<div style="width: 900px;">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="img-responsive"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x350" class="img-responsive"></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="img-responsive"></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="img-responsive"></div>
<div class="col-xs-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="img-responsive"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

So because they are responsive, the 2nd image is higher than the others. Is there a simple way to do an `overflow: hidden;` on the 2nd image and therefor make it the same height as the others? So that the image is not distorted but just cut off at the bottom.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2z1daLwt/

Comment: You could add a `height` property and `overflow: hidden` on the `.row` element.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get `overflow:hidden` to work, you'll have to set the container to a fixed or percentage height, but you don't want to do that for various height and responsive images apparently. Here is the jQuery solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/grpydj1f/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var min = Infinity;
    $els = $('.row > div > img');
    $els.each(function () {
        min = Math.min($(this).height());
    });
    //alert(min);
    $els.parent('div').css({
        'height': min,
        'overflow': 'hidden'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To have different heights and to have bootstrap flow is not really going to work.
Have a look at **[this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518002/bootstrap-3-3-4-picture-grid/30519583#30519583)** where there are some ways to do this.
In my post I show a few options that you might be able to use.
Take a look at my Fiddle and resize the window to see what option suits you best.
I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **.img-responsive** class, this applies **max-width: 100%; height: auto; and display: block;** to each image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.
If you want all of images have the same height, you must set static value for height property for all images by using CSS or add it directly to image tag.